# How to render readme.md in sphinx which contains relative path to some images

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I am using [m2r2](https://pypi.org/project/m2r2/) to render html document using sphinx.
My folder structure is

```
project
  |_ docs
      |_ sphinx root
  |_ README.md
  |_ image_to_include_in_readme.png
```

README.md looks like this:

```
# This is heading

Some text. refer to the image : [Image](image_to_include_in_readme.png)
```

But this image is not readable from sphinx root folder.

I am able to render readme.md correctly using `mdinclude` directive in html but images are not rendered. I am getting  `WARNING: image file not readable:`
I know i can copy the images into build folder but I don't want to do that. How do I fix it?

Comment: Is the file `image_to_include_in_readme.md` an image or a markdown text file? What do you have in your `README.md` that includes the image? How do you include `README.md` into your Sphinx documentation?

Comment: My bad. Its an image file. I am using [m2r2](https://pypi.org/project/m2r2/) `..mdinclude` directive.

Comment: I have updated the question. `mdinclude` is meant for markdown files but how do I link the images in it?

Comment: "I know i can copy the images into build folder but I don't want to do that." You must. Sphinx renders paths to images relative to the built files.

Comment: there is no way to mention relative path to actual image location?

Comment: Seems related: https://github.com/miyakogi/m2r/issues/46

Comment: Yes indeed. Guess we can't do it then :(

Comment: any solution?  I would expect sphinx or m2r2 or whatever to automatically copy the image file into a place the html documentation can see it

Answer (score -1):

ChatGPT-4 suggested adding these lines to conf.py:

```py
# Copy ./examples/results images into documentation so they show up when
# markdown files with relative paths are transcluded
import os
import shutil


def copy_examples(app, docname):
    if app.builder.name == 'html':
        output_dir = os.path.join(app.outdir, 'examples', 'results')
        source_dir = os.path.join(app.srcdir, '..', 'examples', 'results')
        if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(app.outdir, 'examples'))
            shutil.copytree(source_dir, output_dir)


def setup(app):
    app.connect('build-finished', copy_examples)
```

now the file is copied and exists at `https://endolith.github.io/elsim/examples/results/Merrill_1984_Figure_1._25_voters,_10000_iterations.png`, and the README.md file with the relative link to:

```
![](./examples/results/Merrill_1984_Figure_1._25_voters,_10000_iterations.png)
```

included with the line

```
.. mdinclude:: ../README.md
```

Gets converted into html:

```html
<a class="reference external image-reference" href="./examples/results/Merrill_1984_Figure_1._25_voters,_10000_iterations.png">
<img alt="" src="examples/results/Merrill_1984_Figure_1._25_voters,_10000_iterations.png">
</a>
```

which goes to the file that was copied.

Is this the ideal solution?  I have no idea, but it works, despite `make html` still saying:

```
reading sources... [100%] index
../README.md:: WARNING: image file not readable: examples/results/Merrill_1984_Figure_1._25_voters,_10000_iterations.png
```